# How to package AIR 2 native installer?

Tags: java, apache-flex, command-line, air, package

I have made an AIR 2.0 app that uses NativeProcess so it needs to be packaged as a native installer (.exe) rather than a .air file.

I first tried using [Package Assistant](http://www.webkitchen.be/package-assistant-pro/) but I kept getting an error telling me it cannot load keystore file. so I tried using the command line

I use:

```
pathToAirSDK/bin>adt -args
```

but I get an error telling me that

> 'java' is not a recognized as an
> internal or external command...

Has anyone packaged a native installer for an AIR 2.0 app? How did you do it?

#### edit

forgot to mention I am doing this in windows using the windows command line.

Comment: So I installed the Java JDK and it worked.

Comment: So then put your comment as answer and accept it...

Comment: @bug-a-lot I have to wait 48 hours before I can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the Java JDK it worked. I do not know why I needed to have the JDK installed since I was not making a java app.

Comment: You shouldn't need the JDK, just the runtime. The Flex tools are written in Java. It's likely that java.exe wasn't accessible from your command line path, but installing the JDK automatically added it for you by coincidence.